# ng-repeat with filter on several view bug my $index

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have 2 view

view1.html

```
<li ng-repeat="post in posts | filter: { section: 'principal'} ">
```

view2.html

```
<li ng-repeat="post in posts | filter: { section: 'bug' } ">
```

You can see on view1 I have a filter that show only post who have the section "principal" and "bug" for view2.

Now I add a new post with the value "principal", the post appears in the view1 ($index=1).
After I add a post in the view 2 with the value "bug" ($index=2).
Finnaly I add again a new post in view1 ($index =3)

For resume I have 2 post on view1 and 1 post in view2

But I got a problem with the $index if I click on the post on view2, he see he is on the first place on the list so he take index1 and change the first post I create in the view1.

How can I resolve this problem ?

I hope I have made this sufficiently clear.
Thanks for your answer

EDIT :
This is the a button he call the function passerDroite

```
<a class="waves-effect white-text" ng-show="!editing[$index]" ng-click="passerDroite($index)"> >> </a>
```

And this is the function she just modify a "etat" :

```
 $scope.passerDroite = function(index){
        var post = $scope.posts[index];
        post.etat = "enCours";
        Posts.update({id: post._id}, post);
        $scope.editing[index] = false;
    }
```

I just have a little problem with edit :

```
    $scope.editing = [];
    $scope.posts= Posts.query();

    $scope.edit = function(index){
    $scope.editing[index] = angular.copy($scope.posts[index]);
    }
```

I try this :

```
 $scope.edit = function(post){
    post = angular.copy(post);
 }
```

Is it possible to find the index with the post ? Like post.index ?

Comment: First you should use "track by $index" in your ng-repeats. And second., please post the code for the clicks

Comment: I edit my question I show you one function I use with $index

Comment: use `ng-click="passerDroite(post)` and `$scope.passerDroite = function(post){`

Comment: Thanks guy this is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem - try to pass in the actual object instead of the index as Johannes Jander already pointed out `ng-click="passerDroite(post)"` and `function(post){`

Comment: I still have a little bug with the edit function I have edit my post

Comment: As far as i can see in the doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy
the synstax is angular.copy(source, [destination]); so your code should be:
angular.copy(post, destinationpost);